# How to change file path for package.json in Docker?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, express

I'm setting up docker on a personal project and I'm running into a path error.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /Users/Alex/funky-ducks/mediumrare/mediumrare

COPY ./ ./ 

RUN  npm install

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
   mediumrare_docker:
      container_name: container001
      build: /Users/Alex/funky-ducks/mediumrare/mediumrare
      command: npm start
      ports:
         - "3000:3000"
```

This is my directory file structure (note below docker-compose.yml "mediumrare" is the front-end / mediumrare_server is the backend):

```
.
└── mediumrare
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── README.md
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    ├── mediumrare
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── node_modules
    │   ├── package-lock.json
    │   ├── package.json
    │   ├── public
    │   ├── src
    │   └── yarn.lock
    ├── mediumrare_server
    │   ├── node_modules
    │   ├── package-lock.json
    │   ├── package.json
    │   └── server.js
    ├── package-lock.json
    └── package.json
```

I've tried creating a package.json file in the top directory and committing the package-lock.json file.

When I run `docker-compose up` the error message I am receiving is as follows:

```
Creating container001 ... done
Attaching to container001
container001         | npm ERR! path /Users/Alex/funky-ducks/mediumrare/mediumrare/mediumrare_server/package.json
container001         | npm ERR! code ENOENT
container001         | npm ERR! errno -2
container001         | npm ERR! syscall open
container001         | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Alex/funky-ducks/mediumrare/mediumrare/mediumrare_server/package.json'
container001         | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
container001         | npm ERR! enoent 
container001         | 
container001         | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
container001         | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-05-21T17_39_18_298Z-debug.log
container001 exited with code 254
```

I see that when it is being built it is looking for the package.json file inside of the "mediumrare_server" directory. However the package.json file is the top "mediumrare" directory. Why isn't it finding that file and how can I fix this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a similar code locally, and it worked. Your image may be outdated. Rebuild it by running `docker-compose up --build`

---

A couple of notes regarding your Dockerfile

1. First `COPY` `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, run `npm install` then `COPY` source files. This will let you take advantage of layered cache.
2. Is there any reason you have the same directory structure in the container as on the host?
3. You can have `build .` instead of full path in your docker-compose.yml

Comment: Ok, it has worked to get rid of the path error. Now it's throwing an error regarding "shrinkwrap" being set for lockfileVersion:1 but I have lockfileVersion:0. Second, it's throwing an error for not having a "script" but the script would be in the "mediumrare_server" directory. How do I define that path? Right now it wants me to define the path in the package.json file in the top directory when I do that it tells me that nodemon is not found (which is true because it is inside of the "mediumrare_server" directory).

Comment: For the second issue you can try changing `WORKDIR /Users/Alex/funky-ducks/mediumrare/mediumrare/mediumrare_server` then move command from docker-compose to Dockerfile

Comment: That worked, now dealing with the /bin/bash inside of my docker file. It is set up as CMD ["/bin/bash", "start"]. The error I'm getting now is /bin/bash, start: No such file or directory.

Comment: I think you need to have `CMD ["npm", "start"]`